# Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\xampp\htdocs\12work\class.smtp.php on line 197

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail, smtp-auth

I am using XAMPP and when trying to send email through `localhost` I get the following warning:

> **Warning:** `stream_socket_enable_crypto()`: this stream does not support SSL/crypto in `C:\xampp\htdocs\12work\class.smtp.php` on line
>   197

Here is my code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP

$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 25;

$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication

$mail->Username = "sheikh.abm@gmail.com"; // SMTP username

$mail->Password = "mypassword"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "sheikh.abm@gmail.com"; //do NOT fake header.

$mail->FromName = "MailMan";

$mail->AddAddress("sheikh.abm@gmail.com"); // Email on which you want to send mail

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Just a Test";

$mail->Body = "Hello. I am testing <b>PHP Mailer.</b>";

if(!$mail->Send())

{

echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

}else{

echo "email was sent";

}
```

Comment: This went away when I upgraded our Php from 5.3.1 to 5.5 on Centos

Answer (score 51):

Alright, we need to enable ***Open SSL*** module. Here is how to do it:

1. Locate and open your `php.ini` file
2. Search for the line: `;extension=php_openssl.dll`
3. Enable the module by removing **`;`** char.
4. Save the file and restart Apache.

---

**Hint:**
If you are not familiar with `php.ini` file, it is recommended to create a backup before modification. Ini is a configuration file and misconfigured or corrupted ini can result in that web server will not start.

If you are using LAMP stacks such as wamp, it should be possible to enable modules via graphic interface.

More about `php.ini`: **https://secure.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php**

Comment: if i remove ; it gives me this error
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: The 'php_openssl.dll' part did it for me

Comment: I tried it but now I get `PHP Startup: openssl: Unable to initialize module`

Answer (score 4):

In my local system avast mail shield was on I was not allowing any mail to be sent by smtp gmail once I disabled it, the mails were sending in local system via smtp

Comment: ofc it was avast.. (facepalm) thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick note,
you use  `$mail->Port = 25;`

```
 $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
```

Port should be 587 for gmail  /tls
See https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=el

Answer (score 1):

In my local system avast antivirus was on my computer I was not allowing any mail to be sent by SMTP Gmail once I disabled it, the emails were sent in the local system via SMTP

Answer (score -2):

I solved this

Hust close selinux

```
 #setenforce 0
```