# SSL Error in WAMP/XAMPP: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

A week ago I was testing some components in WAMP with PHPMailer and everything worked correctly. The next day it just stopped working. No configuration in WAMP has changed. Using SMTPDebug this is the following error when I try to send an email:

> Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages:error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
>   [C:...\SMTP.php line 404]

I did other tests using the x86 version of WAMP and XAMPP (I currently use x64 WAMP) but without success, I get the same error.

All tests were performed with gmail **"Allow less secure apps"** enabled.

After a quick search in the documentation I discovered that the problem is due to verification of the SSL certificate. And as a workaround I can use the following code to skip this check:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

But as has been said, this is a workaround. I wanted to know where the source of the problem is, I do not understand why it stopped working. I have already tried replacing the certificates in the WAMP / XAMPP folders but without success. Also did extensive research but no results. Any idea how I can solve the certificate verification problem without any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible duplicate: [Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088982/warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1/47093354#47093354)

there is lot of configs that makes this error come up. but more often is that your system's configuration is not set properly. to do it correctly follow this: 1- check if have cacert.pem file for OPENSSL or not if you have not, download proper version from of cacert.pem according to your php version and config your php.ini file as "2-"

2- if you have this file then you have to lookup inside of your php.ini file and see if it has been set in it or not. to do so: lookup for line

```
openssl.cafile ="example address..\cacert.pem"
```

if you find the line with an specific address, look for cacert.pem file in that address, if you find it, than it is all done with cacert.pem file. else, you should use the correct address.

hope this help you.. good luck..!