# production.ERROR: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, email, ssl, laravel-5, smtp

I'm getting this error when trying to send mail from my production server with a Laravel 5.5 project:

```
[2018-07-28 16:05:57] production.ERROR: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: Success at /home/html/my-project/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:94)
```

Meanwhile I'm able to send mail via the same service in my local environment without any errors. I'm also able to send mail from a Laravel 5.4 project on the same server with a similar setup. I checked my `.env` file and how it's being read by `config/mail.php`, and everything appears to be correct.

```
MAIL_DRIVER="smtp"
MAIL_HOST="smtp.sparkpostmail.com"
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION="TLS"
MAIL_AUTHENTICATION="AUTH LOGIN"
MAIL_PASSWORD="mypassword"
MAIL_USERNAME="SMTP_Injection"
```

The accepted answer here ([how to fix stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1)) tells me to add the following to `config/mail.php`:

```
'stream' => [
   'ssl' => [
      'allow_self_signed' => true,
      'verify_peer' => false,
      'verify_peer_name' => false,
   ],
],
```

I tried this but got the same error. I also read that this is not a secure solution for production. This answer ([localhost and "stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423096/localhost-and-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1/44423204)) states that the error is "because you're connecting from localhost, which isn't secure, and that is blocked by the connection. You could avoid that by changing your localhost connection to a SSL based one." But how do I do that on production?

Comment: Ever got around this problem? I'm getting the exact same error on site and I'm clueless.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember how this one resolved.