# Laravel: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, laravel, ssl

The full error description is:

> ErrorException stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed
> with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL
> routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

I am currently using Laravel 7 with Voyager setup (https://voyager.devdojo.com/).

I have this in my config already (based on some other answers)  [how to fix stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1)

```
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
],
```

I did `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan config:clear`

But I am still getting the same error.

This is what my .env looks like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Voyager"
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=someUsername
MAIL_PASSWORD=somePassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: lol that worked. You should convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not an expert on this subject, but you can try MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null.

I am fairly sure I had come across this in the past, and that was the culprit.

Comment: "Not an expert on this subject, but you can send email unencrypted across the internet so anyone can read it."

Comment: @miken32 you do see he has `MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io` set in env. I assume this is not for production use...

Answer (score 6):

Ok I have resolved this error. I changed my .env

I simply changed my **MAIL_DRIVER** from **smtp** to **sendmail** and it is working perfectly fine.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=587 
MAIL_USERNAME=mygmail@gmail.com 
MAIL_PASSWORD=****** 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

when I was working on my localhost then MAIL_DRIVER=smtp was working fine and when I uploaded my project on cpanel then I was getting this error.

Comment: I Love you man, Thanks