# Configure email with TLS in Laravel - Error SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, environment-variables

I want to configure a custom email (not gmail) with TLS using Laravel and I can't make it work.

The error I get is:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
> OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL
> routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

In my `.env` file I have:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.**********.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=system@**********.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=system@**********.com
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I tried the same account in a non Laravel PHP project and it works just fine. In that project, I have this option that I think is the key:

```
$mailer->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$mailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

How can I configure this options in Laravel? Or is another mistake?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30686838/11801683

Comment: As another user said in that post: "that answer doesn't describe the consequences of that change. If you change it to 'mail' it will then send the mail via PHP mail meaning that it will be subject to higher spam scores because PHP is essentially spoofing the email." Tks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally when I change the MAIL_ENCRYPTION to null, it worked just fine. I assume that is a server configuration problem, I'll check it with the sysadmin.
Regards

Comment: Disabling encryption seems like a poor solution to your problem, as does disabling security measures in your "non Laravel PHP project"