# Laravel 8: Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

I'm trying to send a simple email from my laravel 8 app using Google SMTP server, but it doesn't work, I'm getting this error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL:
```

or

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

I found many SO post regarding this issue but none of them worked for me, here's a list of what I have tried:

- Enabling less secure apps in the google account
- using ports 465 and 587
- Using `smtp.googlemail.com` and `smtp.gmail.com`
- Using `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls` and `ssl`
- Changing `'stmp'` to `'sendmail'`
- [Blocking switmailer's ssl constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1)

Is there something else I can try?

Here's my mail configuration, although I've tried many versions of it:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=address@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Comment: check this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1)

Comment: Can you send the mail config please. (Just omit the passwords etc)

Comment: @ChrisTownsend sure, I added it to the question

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, I just disabled my antivirus (Avast / windows 10) and its work.

Comment: You saved me hours bro! Thanks! It worked for me too!

Comment: there no antivirus running on my system but still it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this and add the extra auth mode env variable

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=direction@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
MAIL_AUTH_MODE=login
```

Now go to `config/mail.php`

and change

```
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => null,
    ],
```

to

```
    'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
        'auth_mode' => env('MAIL_AUTH_MODE'),
    ],
```

Comment: It keeps failing... throws the second error message shown in the question

Comment: Random one. Does your environment have the correct date and time set your the timezone your are in?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was a problem with Windows. I found some posts pointing that windows just can't execute some mail services. I tried the exact same code in a computer with Ubuntu and it worked at first try.