# Error trying to send email with Symfony Mailer

Tags: windows, symfony, symfony-4.4, symfony-mailer

How do you configure Symfony Mailer? I'm swapping Swiftmailer to Symfony Mailer because Swiftmailer is now deprecated. However, I haven't been able to send a single email with Symfony Mailer yet. Swiftmailer always works and the emails are caught by smtp4dev.

Platform:

- Windows 10
- Symfony 4.4
- smtp4dev listening on port 25

`mailer.yaml`

```yaml
framework:
  mailer:
    dsn: 'smtp://localhost'
```

Error message:

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

Comment: Looks like [TLS Verification](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#tls-peer-verification). Try with `dsn: 'smtp://localhost?verify_peer=0'`.

Comment: @Bossman That made no difference. Are these options documented somewhere?

Comment: There is a link in my comment, that page is the docs for the mailer and specifically for the *verify_peer* option. From the error message it looks like it might be the local server software blocking it, like XAMPP for example or whatever you're using..

Comment: [This may be of help also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1). It's a cert issue somewhere..

Comment: @Bossman There's no mention of "TLS" on the 4.4 page. Does smtp have certificates? And on `localhost`?

Comment: I think the Symfony mailer component has the checks. Yes smtp has certs, you can generate localhost certs. Like i say from the error it looks like your server software might have settings to point to certs maybe, not 100% sure..

Comment: @Bossman Wouldn't that be smtps (465), not smtp (25)? Why would it need a certificate if it's not secure?