# Laravel 5.4 with stream_socket_enable_crypto failure

Tags: laravel, email

ERROR WHEN SENDING MAIL

stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

**.env setup**

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:JZ8iPKOEV8Ozfw7dQk08kMnK2fcakf1cQxGBsrDH+Ok=
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=******.***.***.**
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_ENCRPYTION=ssl / tls / “” / not present at all
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=***@***.***.**
```

These are all the combos I tried on  MAIL_ENCRPYTION

```
MAIL_ENCRPYTION=ssl / tls / “” / not present at all
```

Applied **cacert.pem** in **php.ini** file

Works when applying this solution to mail.php (below) but need a secure

```
-          'stream' => [
-            'ssl' => [
-              'allow_self_signed' => true,
-              'verify_peer' => false,
-              'verify_peer_name' => false,
-            ],
-          ],
```

Comment: where did you get this `cacert.pem`? did you make it yourself (assuming so given `allow_self_signed` is true)?

Comment: From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63450019/2240163

Comment: may we know what is the mail service you used? there are many stuffs need to be checked such as (but not limited to): 1) supported ssl/tls version; 2) port number (make sure you hit the one that supports the secure channel); 3) their certificate is valid