# OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Tags: php, laravel, openssl, xampp, composer-php

I am using PHP v7.2, on Windows 10 Computer and Composer version 1.9.0

`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog`

I am trying to install Laravel and start a project using composer but getting the following error

> OpenSSL Error messages:
> error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

When I run `composer diagnose` getting below result

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\webstore_services> composer diagnose
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: Warning: Accessing 192.168.1xx.2xx over http which is an insecure protocol.
OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version:
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                        
  The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:  
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed                                            
  Failed to enable crypto                                                                                                         
  failed to open stream: operation failed                                                                                         
diagnose
```

I have tried almost every solution on the Internet

`php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations());"`

Result

```
(
    [default_cert_file] => C:\usr\local\ssl/cert.pem
    [default_cert_file_env] => SSL_CERT_FILE
    [default_cert_dir] => C:\usr\local\ssl/certs
    [default_cert_dir_env] => SSL_CERT_DIR
    [default_private_dir] => C:\usr\local\ssl/private
    [default_default_cert_area] => C:\usr\local\ssl
    [ini_cafile] => C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem
    [ini_capath] => C:\xampp\php\cacert.pem
)
```

How will I change the location of `default_cert_file` in this, Only this is left?

Since I am on Corporate Proxy I have set the env-variable of the proxy.

https_proxy : http://user:pass@host:port
http_proxy : http://user:pass@host:port

After everything I do, it doesn't help me though.

Comment: Try this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511717/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-verification-failure)

Comment: My computer's time is correct

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to a openssl verify command using the server certificate and the cacert.pem certificate list.  Something like "openssl verify  -CAfile cacert.pem -untrusted server.pem server.pem". My guess, your server cert doesn't have intermediate certificates in it.  https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/verify.html

Comment: I too am having this exact problem. composer 1.8.5, also behind corporate firewall. Not using laravel.  Do you also get an error when running `composer self-update`?  Something like: The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
  error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
  Failed to enable crypto
  failed to open stream: operation failed

Comment: @Protomancer Yes I get this issue on `composer self-update`

Comment: check my answer here it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/60709451/5068530

Answer (score 6):

I do not know if I will answer you, but I will try to enlighten you:

it is a secure connection failure:
default_cert_file is defined when you generate the certificate

error:1416F086:SSL is an error like
**the server rejected your certificate because it is revoked, nonexistent or incorrect**
the *same* error can occur in a browser with Error code: SSL_ERROR_REVOKED_CERT_ALERT or SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALER when the security certificate is not or no longer valid

when you generate a root certificate this can depend on a configuration file in which is specified several information, notably the path:

[CA_default]
dir = ./certificats #  Where everything is kept

openssl etc ...

I think what you're looking for is akin

**SSL context options
SSL context options — SSL context option listing**

cafile string

```
Location of Certificate Authority file on local filesystem which should be used with the verify_peer context option to authenticate the identity of the remote peer.
```

capath string

```
If cafile is not specified or if the certificate is not found there, the directory pointed to by capath is searched for a suitable certificate. capath must be a correctly hashed certificate directory.
```

Answer (score 2):

most common cause of this error is out of sync date/time, check what is your machine's local time and use commands like ntp or chrony to sync your time.

If you are having this problem in a docker container, the container would be using your host time. However, putting the computer in hibernate mode would make the time lock up. the only solution is to restart the whole computer.

Comment: Hey my machine local time and server time are the same.

Comment: Thank you so much this was my issue on an Ubuntu setup using gRPC

Comment: @MewTwo check timezone too

Answer (score 0):

I found this while I was searching for a similar issue, so I might spare few minutes to write something that others might benefit from.

Sometimes corporate proxies terminate secure sessions to check if you don't do any malicious stuff, then sign it again, but with their own CA certificate that is trusted by your OS, but might not be trusted by openssl. You can check that with the openssl itself:

```
openssl s_client -connect fully.qualified.domain.name:port
```

The command above should provide you with the certificate that was presented. Just look for:

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/long/DN/rewritten/from/the/original/certificate
   i:/proxy/issuer/certificate
 1 s:/proxy/issuer/certificate
   i:/corporate/root/CA
 2 s:/corporate/root/CA
   i:/corporate/root/CA
---
```

So basically you want to have the root CA certificate trusted.

Answer (score -1):

Recently, full certificate chain in pfx, jks etc. is often required on web server side. In such case web server sends all certificates from CA to the server one during SSL handshake so the other party has to trust just the CA.