# Symfony 5 Issue with mailing

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, symfony5, mailer

I ran into an issue while creating my registration form in Symfony 5.

Those are the commands I used to be able to build it.

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my_project_name
symfony console make:controller HomeController
composer require symfony/security-bundle
symfony console make:user
composer require --dev symfony/maker-bundle
symfony console make:registration-form
```

After that I set my MAILER_DSN and MAILER_URL and a username field in the form. And then, when I register, here is the error I have :

> "Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
> error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed"

I checked in my database and the user is registred in it. But I guess it's about the mailing system for the confirmation of the registration.

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls\_process\_server\_certificate:certificate verify failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358047/openssl-error-messages-error1416f086ssl-routinestls-process-server-certifica)

Answer (score 0):

For Gmail you need `composer req symfony/google-mailer`

And your `MAILER_DSN` should look like this `gmail+smtp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@default`

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html

Comment: I put that in .env.local file, so username is the email adress i suppose 
nothing is changing i have the same issue.

yes yes i installed, google mailer bundle