# I am using laravel version 6. I received below error when try to reset password. How can I Solve this error

Tags: php, laravel

Error :
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed. how can I solve this.....

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:QhycgUHvEwfLKHwI4kEFxue3f6dOu+xOBDIRfQIkydo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/
 MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
`MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com`
`MAIL_PORT=587`
`MAIL_USERNAME=*@gmail.com`

MAIL_PASSWORD=*

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${Inqiry_MS}"
```

mail.php

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
```

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978459/warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-this-stream-does-not-support-ssl-crypto/60709451#60709451

Comment: Ensure your system has a properly installed CA bundle and that PHP is configured with its location.